# EF Core Filtering

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have something that currently looks like this and works in EF Core:

```
DbContext.Computers.OrderByDirection(state.SortDirection, 
    x => x.Actions.FirstOrDefault(y => y.GetType() == typeof(PingAction) && 
    y.History.Any(z => z.Status == Status.Succeeded && 
    (DateTime.Now - z.WhenExecuted).TotalMinutes < 10)))
```

However I also need to use the `x` function elsewhere and don't want to hard code it multiple times. How can I save that function to a variable or something and still allow it to work with the server sided filtering of EF core since of course this will be translated to SQL?

**UPDATE**

Signatures for `OrderByDirection`:

```
public static IOrderedEnumerable<TSource> OrderByDirection<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, SortDirection direction, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector)
public static IOrderedQueryable<TSource> OrderByDirection<TSource, TKey>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, SortDirection direction, Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>> keySelector)
```

Comment: Is OrderByDirection a custom extension method? You can probably save the function definition in an Expression and forward that to this method and use it elsewhere if you have to. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/

Comment: @fbede Ooops, didn't realise it but you're right, it belongs to MudBlazor which I'm using of course.

Comment: @fbede what would my expression look like and how would I pass it?

Comment: can you add the method header of OrderByDirection? Especially the parameter types.

Comment: @fbede added it yesterday :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could extract the expression into a variable similarly to this:

(I am only guessing the class names by your property names, they aren't obvious from your code):

```
Expression<Func<Computer, Action>> expression = x => x.Actions.FirstOrDefault(
    action => action.GetType() == typeof(PingAction) && action.History.Any(
        history => history.Status == Status.Succeeded && (DateTime.Now - z.WhenExecuted).TotalMinutes < 10));

DbContext.Computers.OrderByDirection(state.SortDirection, expression);
```

then this expression can be reused elsewhere.